# local dev server and app engine python utf 8

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, utf-8, google-cloud-datastore

In building a website in GAE.
I did most of the work in the dev server where I have a database. In my dev server I inserted the entities in UTF-8 because if I don't the values are not writen. However, this makes me have to use `{{ nom.titre.encode("utf-8")}}` in order to display them correctly with jinja2.
I know that GAE datastore only uses UNICODE so I could anticipate the problem that I'm facing now.

So, I used `appcfg.py download_data --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=filename.csv --kind=-kind-` 
to get a backup of my dev datastore.

Now the problem is when I try to update to the server.

**Either I use :**

- `appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://as.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --kind=kind --filename=filename.csv`
  But the {{ nom.titre.encode("utf-8")}} makes an error on GAE with jinja

***OR***

- `appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=G:\Backup\datastore\bulkloader.yaml --url=http://toolsetdocs.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api`
  with

  ```
  transformers:
  - kind: CISP
    connector: csv
    connector_options:
      encoding: utf-8
  ```

  and I get an error with `UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf-8' codec can't decode` ..... and so on

So, what is the **most direct way** to upload the info of my dev server datastore into the GAE datastore keeping the UTF-8 AND not changing the template encoding?

Comment: Please post the code that shows persistence to the datastore.

Comment: I found the solution. In fact everything handles UNICODE, the development datastore, GAE datastore and Jinja2. So, I got the data in JSON, putted in the GAE datastore without any further encoding or decoding on the Python script. Then I downloaded it on my PC and uploaded it to the development datastore. The strings containing special caracters (for example "Système digestif") don't show up in the development datastore but I still have access to them whitout further encoding / decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store the strings, you should use `decode('utf-8')` and then encode for display purposes. You are currently doing this in the template, but you should be decoding the expected UTF-8 string when you are storing it.

Comment: So, in other words you are saying that I have have to do the other way around. Put UNICODE in the datastore and then display it in UTF-8? If I have the same problem again I'll use this hint. Thank you

Comment: Yes. As you said, GAE data store stores it in Unicode, but at display time, you can encode it however you want.